# Count 2 distinct fields in same mysql row in 1 query

Tags: mysql

Here is my table:

```
id     |    fielded    |    attended
=====================================
1           Greg            Chris
2           James           Chris
3           Greg            James
```

My query is as follows:

```
Select DISTINCT(fielded), count(fielded) as fielded_count FROM fielded_calls group by fielded
```

The Output that I would like to see is:

```
fielded    |    fielded_count    |    attended_count
====================================================
Chris           0                     2
Greg            2                     0
James           1                     1
```

How can I add the attended count that is based off of the unique name in the 'fielded' column?  I have tried UNION and subqueries with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to make a list of all the unique names in the table by a `UNION` of the names in the `fielded` column and the names in the `attended` column. This derived table can then be `LEFT JOIN`ed to your original table to get the counts you desire:

```
SELECT n.name AS fielded,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c1.id) AS fielded_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c2.id) AS attended_count
FROM (SELECT fielded AS name FROM fielded_calls
      UNION
      SELECT attended FROM fielded_calls) n
LEFT JOIN fielded_calls c1 ON c1.fielded = n.name
LEFT JOIN fielded_calls c2 ON c2.attended = n.name
GROUP BY fielded
```

Output:

```
fielded     fielded_count   attended_count
Chris       0               2
Greg        2               0
James       1               1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eo5VSz7fCTaX2pwiormBku/1)

Comment: If you add the value to your dbfiddle, ('4', 'Chris', 'Greg');  It then gives out inaccurate counts for Greg - attended and Chris - fielded.  Do you know why it does that?

Comment: I added DISTINCT to the COUNT statements and it fixed that problem.

Comment: @osakagreg sorry about lack of response - it's been night time here. I'm glad you resolved the issue. I've updated the answer and demo for future users who might find this question.